# "Connection Refused" error while trying to run Python script to establish MQTT on Jetson

Tags: linux, mqtt, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to establish MQTT on Jetson and it gives me "Connection refused" error, while running python script which includes my broker IP and port. while checking netstats -at i can find only port 5900 and not 1883. How do I modify this on the config file? Can someone give a detailed steps to follow.

Verified the configuration file for the ufw firewall and re-installed ufw.
Allowed access for all devices on port 1883.
Successfully pinged the broker address through a Windows PC.
Uninstalled and re-installed both Mosquitto and Paho on the Jetson.
Confirmed the status of Paho by running a Python script, which worked as expected.
Successfully established a publisher and subscriber on the Jetson, testing communication successfully.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77543566/edit) the question to include the python code and details of how you have configured moquitto? Also is the broker running on the same machine as the client? You should probably include the mosquitto logs as well

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate based on some guesses as there is not enough information in the question to answer it properly. If this is not the case edit the question to include the details I asked for and I'll reopen it.